# Refer to extension function defined as a member; inlining `with`

Tags: kotlin

Say I have the following:

```
object Foo {
    fun Int.negate() = -this
    fun negateInt(n: Int) = -n
}
```

I can call the extension method `negate` on `Foo` by using `with`:

```
fun main() {
  println(with(Foo) { 5.negate() }) // prints -5
}
```

I can call the other method by calling it on the `Foo` object:

```
fun main2() {
    println(Foo.negateInt(5)) // prints -5
}
```

I think `with(Foo) { 5.negate() }` is syntactically a bit on the heavy side compared to `Foo.negateInt(5)` when the body is just a single invocation. I can't find a more compact way to perform this call though. I had hoped that I could do `Foo::negate` to get a function `(Int) -> Int` where `this` has been lifted to be an argument, just like I can do for normal non-extension methods. For example, `val f = Int::toString` will give me a function `(Int) -> String` such that `f(42)` is equivalent to `42.toString()`. If I could do that, then I could write `(Foo::negate)(5)` which is still heavy, but less heavy than `with(Foo) { ... }`.

Is there really no way to explicitly refer to an extension method defined as a member?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer directly. For that you just need to import the extension function to your current package:

```
import Foo.negate
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
println(5.negate())
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but only when the object is a top-level singleton. I was actually after something a bit more general. For example, if I have `class Bar(val offset: Int) { fun Int.negate() = offset - this }` and then set `val bar = Bar(42)`, then I still cannot refer to `bar.negate`.

Comment: looks like you are missing the point of extension functions, all extension functions should be static, otherwise the compiler will not know which one to pick. What you are trying to achieve can be done with plain method calls, extension functions are used to extend the functionality of a class.

Comment: No? They are statically resolved, but they can very well live in dynamically allocated objects, and in fact they can be closures. Case in point, I can write `with(bar) { 5.negate() }` without any problems.

Comment: The only viable variant I find with classes is to inherit then  `class Bar : Foo() {
    fun test() {
        println(5.negate())
    }
}`, in Foo all extension methods are defined

Comment: I actually tried that as well. Unfortunately it also does not work for the use case I have, because of limitations due to type erasure. E.g. have `interface Monoid<A> { fun z(): A fun A.add(other:A):A }` and want to implement `class PairIsMon<A,B>(val monA: Monoid<A>, val monB: Monoid<B>): Monoid<Pair<A,B>>, Monoid<A> by monA, Monoid<B> by monB { ... }`. This would actually be *really* nice if it worked, but I am not allowed to inherit from `Monoid` twice with different type arguments, because of type erasure...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the best you can get

```
class Bar(val offset: Int) { fun Int.negate() = offset - this }

fun main() { 
    val bar = Bar(42)
    bar.run { 5.negate() }
}
```

Comment: Yes I think so, unfortunately. It's the same as writing `with(bar) { 5.negate() }` though.

Comment: looks a bit better imo